# R - Procurar linhas em um data frame condicionado a parte de uma string

Tags: r

Tenho um data frame com várias linhas, nessas linhas tenho uma frase que contém por padrão a palavra "Anúncio", quero gerar um novo data frame que contenha somente as linhas que na frase possuem a palavra "Anúncio". Já procurei em vários links de como fazer isso no R mas ainda não encontrei a solução.

```
Exemplo:

#Gerar um novo data frame com os dados a serem trabalhados das visualizações de anúncios
DadosAnuncios=data.frame(Usuário=Dados[,1],DescricaoURL=Dados[,6])
#Pegar somente as descrições que são dos anúncios
DadosAnuncios=DadosAnuncios[grep("Anúncio:", DadosAnuncios$DescricaoURL),]
View(table(DadosAnuncios[,2]))
```

Exemplo 2:

```
Usuarios=c("Joao1", "Joao2", "Joao3", "Joao4")
Acessos=c("Página 01", "Página 02", "Anúncio: 01", "Anúncio: 02")
MeusDados=data.frame(Usuarios,Acessos)
DadosAnunciosTeste=MeusDados[grep("Anúncio:", MeusDados$Acessos),]
View(table(DadosAnunciosTeste[,2]))
```

Comment: Seria legal você disponibilizar o seu banco de dados, ou uma parte do mesmo, para utilização como exemplo. Além disso, o que você já tentou? Coloque também seu código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contando que seu `data.frame` seja `dados` e a coluna que contenha a palavra "Anúncio" seja `frase`,

```
dados[grep("Anúncio", dados$frase),]
```

deve resolver seu problema

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, essa solução deu certo! Só que quando vou gerar uma tabela de frequência de um atributo deste novo dataframe através da função 'table' a tabela de frequência gerada traz a frequência das linhas que foram extraídas mas também traz as linhas do antigo dataframe porém com frequência zeradas! Para melhor entendimento segue abaixo um exemplo:

Comment: teria como você colocar seus dados, ou uma parte do mesmo? utilize o comando `dput` para que a gente posso reproduzir o seu problema

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei um código de exemplo.

Comment: o código de exemplo está ok, mas é importante disponibilizar os dados

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta um exemplo 2 de amostra de como são meus dados, pois não sei fazer isso que você pediu rsrs...comecei a usar esse o site recentemente.

Comment: para você colocar seu banco de dados aqui, digite `dput(Dados)` no `R` e copie e cole a saída aqui no site. Mas quanto ao seu comentário, ele está aparecendo as frequências zeradas, pois o código `MeusDados <- data.frame(Usuarios,Acessos)` modifica a classe das variáveis para `factor`. Transforme-as em `character`

Comment: Não entendi a parte da conversão da variável para `character`... Quando gero o novo dataframe `DadosAnunciosTeste` ele só possui duas instâncias, mas ao exibir a tabela de frequência, são mostradas as quatro instâncias.

Comment: rode o comando `str(DadosAnuncios)` e, se eu estiver correto, vai aparecer que as suas duas variáveis são fatores. O que eu recomento é, depois de rodar `DadosAnuncios=data.frame(Usuário=Dados[,1], DescricaoURL=Dados[,6])`, transforme suas variáveis em `character`, com o comando `DadosAnuncios <- as.character(DadosAnuncios[,1])` e `DadosAnuncios <- as.character(DadosAnuncios[,2])`

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma será a seguinte.
Primeiro vamos criar uma tabela artificial, só para teste.

```
set.seed(2203)    # torna os resultados reprodutíveis

s <- 
"Tenho um data frame com várias linhas, nessas linhas tenho uma frase que contém por padrão a palavra Anúncio, quero gerar um novo data frame que contenha somente as linhas que na frase possuem a palavra Anúncio. Já procurei em vários links de como fazer isso no R mas ainda não encontrei a solução"
s <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", s), " "))
dados <- data.frame(s = sample(s, 200, TRUE), x = rnorm(200))
```

Agora vou usar `grepl` para encontrar a palavra `anúncio`. Como pode estar presente tanto capitalizada como não, também uso `tolower`, para ter a certeza que não há esse problema.

```
inx <- grepl("anúncio", tolower(dados$s))
anuncio <- dados[which(inx), ]
row.names(anuncio) <- NULL
anuncio
#        s          x
#1 Anúncio -0.2342417
#2 Anúncio -2.2457881
#3 Anúncio  0.7579141
#4 Anúncio  0.7771827
#5 Anúncio -1.5996622
#6 Anúncio  1.0020413
```